# SQLAlchemy Many-to-Many Relationship on a Single Table

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I have a SQLAlchemy model set up in my application that should mimic the functionality of "followers" on Twitter, ie. users have have a many-to-many relationship with eachother (both followers and following).  The tables are structured as follows (sa is the sqlalchemy module):

```
t_users = sa.Table("users", meta.metadata,
    sa.Column("id", sa.types.Integer, primary_key=True),
    sa.Column("email", sa.types.String(320), unique=True, nullable=False),
    ...etc...
    )

t_follows = sa.Table("follows", meta.metadata,
    sa.Column("id", sa.types.Integer, primary_key=True),
    sa.Column("follower_id", sa.types.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False),
    sa.Column("followee_id", sa.types.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
    )
```

I've run into a bit of a roadblock however, trying to use orm.mapper to create this relationship, since the secondary table refers back to the same primary table in both directions.  How would I go about mapping this relationship to the ORM?

Comment: Self-referential table case has a section in documentation: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/join_conditions.html#self-referential-many-to-many

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to write `primaryjoin` and `secondaryjoin` conditions explicitly in this case:

```
mapper(
    User, t_users,
    properties={
        'followers': relation(
            User,
            secondary=t_follows,
            primaryjoin=(t_follows.c.followee_id==t_users.c.id),
            secondaryjoin=(t_follows.c.follower_id==t_users.c.id),
        ),
        'followees': relation(
            User,
            secondary=t_follows,
            primaryjoin=(t_follows.c.follower_id==t_users.c.id),
            secondaryjoin=(t_follows.c.followee_id==t_users.c.id),
        ),
    },
)
```

I've wrote this sample verbose to help you understand better what `primaryjoin` and `secondaryjoin` parameters mean. Sure, you can make it sorter with `backref`.

BTW, you don't need `id` column in follows table, use composite primary key instead. In fact, you should define unique constraint of `follower_id` and `followee_id` pair anyway (either as primary or additional unique key).

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly.  Did you mean that the follows table doesn't require an ID column and can use a composite PK?  I don't see how that could work with the users table.

Comment: Yes, it was a mistake. I meant follows table.

Comment: I ran into this and had to do it declaratively, here's the equivalent for future finders.

Comment: @DenisOtkidach can you elaborate simply what secondary join and primaryjoin does?

Comment: As @Zion says, would be helpful to elaborate on the primary and secondary joins. However here is the doc: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#specifying-alternate-join-conditions

Answer (score 24):

You can also do this declaratively.

Here is a similar example based on the above code, I do use the backref.

```
VolumeRelationship = Table(
    'VolumeRelationship', Base.metadata,
    Column('ParentID', Integer, ForeignKey('Volumes.ID')),
    Column('VolumeID', Integer, ForeignKey('Volumes.ID'))
    )

class Volume(Base):
    """ Volume Object """
    __tablename__ = "Volumes"

    id = Column('ID', Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    type = Column('Type', String(25))
    name = Column('Name', String(25))
    poolid = Column('pool', Integer, ForeignKey('Pools.ID'))
    parents = relation(
                    'Volume',secondary=VolumeRelationship,
                    primaryjoin=VolumeRelationship.c.VolumeID==id,
                    secondaryjoin=VolumeRelationship.c.ParentID==id,
                    backref="children")
```

Comment: For me, I had to add analogue of
`foreign_keys =
   [VolumeRelationship.c.VolumeID,
   VolumeRelationship.c.ParentID])` to `Volume.parents`, otherwise I had `NoReferencedTableError`.

Comment: Self-referential table case has a section in documentation: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/join_conditions.html#self-referential-many-to-many