# Many-to-many relationship on same table with association object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Related (for the no-association-object use case): [SQLAlchemy Many-to-Many Relationship on a Single Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889251/sqlalchemy-many-to-many-relationship-on-a-single-table)

Building a many-to-many relationship is easy. Building a many-to-many relationship on the same table is almost as easy, as documented in the above question.

Building a many-to-many relationship with an association object is also easy.

What I can't seem to find is the right way to combine association objects and many-to-many relationships with the left and right sides being the same table.

So, starting from the simple, naïve, and clearly wrong version that I've spent forever trying to massage into the *right* version:

```
t_groups = Table('groups', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
)

t_group_groups = Table('group_groups', metadata,
    Column('parent_group_id', Integer, ForeignKey('groups.id'), primary_key=True, nullable=False),
    Column('child_group_id', Integer, ForeignKey('groups.id'), primary_key=True, nullable=False),
    Column('expires', DateTime),
)

mapper(Group_To_Group, t_group_groups, properties={
    'parent_group':relationship(Group),
    'child_group':relationship(Group),
})
```

What's the *right* way to map this relationship?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you are getting an error like `Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables...`
In this case, Change the mapper for `Group_To_Group` to the following:

```
mapper(Group_To_Group, t_group_groups, properties={
    'parent_group':relationship(Group,
        primaryjoin=(t_group_groups.c.parent_group_id==t_groups.c.id),),
    'child_group':relationship(Group,
        primaryjoin=(t_group_groups.c.child_group_id==t_groups.c.id),),
})
```

also you might want to add the `backref` so that you can navigate the relations from the `Group` objects as well.

Comment: I must have been doing something subtly wrong last night. That did it, though, thanks!