# Declarative relationships between two instance of the same object type in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to achieve (what I can only now call *the infamous*) many-to-many or association pattern in SQLAlchemy, but to the same table. My requirement is to be able to define a *Relationship* as linking two *Roles*.

Regarding only the **columns** in the ORM, below is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
class Relationship(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'relationship'
    id = Column(Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    subject_id = Column(ForeignKey('role.id'), primary_key=True)
    object_id = Column(ForeignKey('role.id'), primary_key=True)
    relationship_name = Column(String)

class Role(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'role'
    id = Column(Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
```

I've tried adapting the pattern at [SQLAlchemy Many-to-Many](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many), but of course I run into the *multiple join paths problem*. I would prefer not to use the association pattern, because I want to augment data to the Relationship and so have it available as a class.

How can I do this in the declarative style?

Comment: Regarding the declarative preference, [this is a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889251/sqlalchemy-many-to-many-relationship-on-a-single-table) that does not declare a class.